# Strings in a separate .pas file

Tags: delphi, pascal

This may not be the correct place for this question, if not feel free to move it. I tagged as Delphi/Pascal because it's what I am working in atm, but this could apply to all programming I guess.

Anyway I am doing some code cleanup and thinking of moving all the strings in my program to a separate single .pas file. Are there any pros and cons to doing this? Is it even worth doing?

To clarify: I mean that I will be creating a separate file, Strings.pas in it I will make all my text string variables.

Ex

Current Code

```
 Messages.Add('The voucher was NOT sent to ' + sName+
                          ' because the application is in TEST MODE.');
 Messages.Add('Voucher Saved to ' + sFullPath);
 Messages.Add('----------------------------------------------------------');
```

New Code would be something like:

```
Messages.Add(sMsgText1 + '' + sName + '' + sMsgText2 + '' + sFullPath)
```

The Strings.pas file would hold all the string data. Hope that makes better sense

Comment: Why would you do such thing?You can of course place the strings in some other .pas file,then parse the .pas file in your file that contains code and use that strings,though in that case,I'll  give the strings file extension .txt.

Comment: You can do that by loading the file into a string then parsing the string.I don't know pascal,so I can't give you an example.

Comment: @Aleksandar OP is thinking of writing a .pas file that contains a long list of `const` declarations.

Comment: I don't know about pascal.But in c,you can declare a header file,containing only constants(defines,typedefs and const vars)

Comment: @Aleksandar, if you don't know Delphi or Pascal, why are you trying to answer the question (even in comments)? :)

Comment: @Ken: I think it is a rather universal problem, that has a similar solution in C, C#, etc. as it has in Pascal. But one wonders a little indeed.

Comment: In .Net the standard way are resource string files (also to support multi-culture apps)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moving your strings to a separate file is a good idea!  It keeps them together and will let you easily change them if required.  Your question doesn't say you want to be able to translate them, but centralizing will help that to.

But, code like:

```
Messages.Add(sMsgText1 + '' + sName + '' + sMsgText2 + '' + sFullPath)
```

is *not* better than code like:

```
Messages.Add('The voucher was NOT sent to ' + sName+
                      ' because the application is in TEST MODE.');
```

**You've turned a messy but readable function call into a messy and *un*-readable function call**.  With the old code (the second snippet just above), you can read the code and see roughly what the message is going to say, because a lot of it is there in text.  With the new code, you can't.

Second, the reason for moving the strings to to keep related items together and make it easier to change them.  What if you want to change the above message so that instead of saying "The file 'foo' in path 'bar'..." it is phrased "The file bar\foo is..."?  You can't: the way the messages are built is still fixed and scattered throughout your code.  If you want to change several messages to be formatted the same way, you will need to change lots of individual places.

This will be even more of a problem if your goal is to translate your messages, since often translation requires rephrasing a message not just translating the components.  (You need to change the order of subitems included in your messages, for example - you can't just assume each language is a phrase-for-phrase in order substitution.)

### Refactor one step further

I'd suggest instead a more aggressive refactoring of your message code.  You're definitely on the right track when you suggest moving your messages to a separate file.  But don't just move the strings: move the functions as well.  Instead of a large number of `Messages.Add('...')` scattered through your code, find the common subset of messages you create.  Many will be very similar.  Create a family of functions you can call, so that all similar messages are implemented with a single function, and if you need to change the phrasing for them, you can do it in a single spot.

For example, instead of:

```
Messages.Add('The file ' + sFile + ' in ' + sPath + ' was not found.');
... and elsewhere:
Messages.Add('The file ' + sFileName + ' in ' + sURL + ' was not found.');
```

have a single function:

```
Messages.ItemNotFound(sFile, sPath);
...
Messages.ItemNotFound(sFileName, sURL);
```

You get:

- Centralized message strings
- Centralized message functions
- Less code duplication
- Cleaner code (no assembling of strings in a function call, just parameters)
- Easier to translate - provide an alternate implementation of the functions (don't forget that just translating the substrings may not be enough, you often need to be able to alter the phrasing substantially.)
- Clear descriptions of what the message is in the function name, such as `ItemNotFount(item, path)`, which leads to
- Clearer code when you're reading it

Sounds good to me :)

Comment: While this though process came along while I was thinking of change for the sake of change, I also clearly see the pros and cons. @David M, I am accepting your answer as the answer because you have sent me in a very good direction.

Comment: @JamesW - I've found that using formatStrings is very helpful for this type of work. Define a string constant, for example: 'const eMsg='file %s was not found'. Then call your central function formatting the constant: Messages.ItemNotFound(format(eMsg,['missing_file']))

Answer (score 7):

I think it makes a lot of sense to move all string constants to a single unit. It makes changing the texts a lot easier, especially if you want to translate to other (human) languages.

But instead of strings, why don't you do what I usually do, i.e. use resourcestring. That way, your strings can be changed by someone else with a resource editor, without recompilation.

```
unit Strings;

resourcestring
  strMsgText1 = 'The voucher was NOT sent to ';

etc...
```

But such a string is probably better done as:

```
resourcestring
  strVoucherNotSent = 
    'The voucher was NOT sent to %s because the application is in TEST MODE.';
  strVoucherForNHasValueOf =
    'The voucher for %s has a value of $%.2f';
```

The advantage of that is that in some languages, the placement and order of such substitutions is different. That way, a translator can place the arguments wherever it is necessary. Of course the application must then use Format() to handle the string:

```
Messages.Add(Format(strVoucherNotSent, [sName]));
Messages.Add(Format(strVoucherSavedTo, [sFullPath]));
Messages.Add(Format(strVoucherForNHasValueOf, [sName, dblValue]));
```

Comment: You are not mentioning the downside of moving all strings, constants etc. into separate files. They are then dislocated from the code which refers to them and that can make maintenance hard. A good example is the last line of code in your answer. I think this is one of those issues where you have competing concerns that pull in opposite directions. Each approach has both pros and cons.

Comment: I think it makes maintenance easier, or at least not harder at all. Instead of using literal strings, he should use meaningful constant names. Maintenance of the texts is a lot easier. It is IMO what everyone writing a non-trivial program should do.

Comment: In what way is the last line of code in my answer problematic? The name of the constant makes perfectly clear what the text is supposed to convey, although it does not give the exact text. For translations, where the value should perhaps be placed before the name, that is the only useful solution. In that case, the format string should of course use formatting to indicate which argument is being used where.

Comment: As soon as the outputting logic gets complex then it becomes very confusing if your text is hidden away in a different location.

Comment: @David: I entirely disagree. I don't think it is confusing at all. It is clear where ALL texts are: in that single unit. In the spearate unit, they can be grouped by purpose or unit, and separated by en empty line and a comment. And it also makes it easier to be consistent in spelling, grammar, etc. IMO, it is a Good Programming Practice. But let's agree that we disagree. People should do what they want. I merely wanted to show how it could be done, and that there are people, like me, who think that it makes a lot of sense. Did you notice that the RTL and VCL do this too?

Comment: @David: you mentioned complex output logic. What did you mean?

Comment: Loops, decisions, pluralisation, layout. I often find myself piecing together bits of text.

Comment: VCL is the way it is because it is translated. VCL  also has many orders of magnitude less text, and less complex output logic than the app I work with.

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to translate the UI into different languages then you may benefit from having all your text in a single file, or perhaps a number of files dedicated to declaring string constants.

However, if you do this change without such a strong motivation, then you may just make your code hard to read.

Generally you have to ask what the benefits of such a major refactoring are, and if they are not self-evident, then you may well be changing things just for the sake of change.

Comment: The best example I can think of now is glade.The GUI builder for GTK exporting .xml files.

Comment: I was thinking along these same lines. The main motivation is that some of the applications use very similar or the even the same text multiple times. I know I could just declare them as global constants but that's when I got to thinking if I am going to do some as global constants why not just do all of them and park them in a different file.

Comment: @JamesW Declare the duplicates as shared constants for sure. But you don't need to change your entire application in this way.

Comment: The more I thought about it, the more I saw that it may have been change for the sake of change. I see small benefits in doing so (Locate and edit strings quickly being the main one.) The cons seem to outweigh however, time to implement, readability for others who may need to modify my code etc.

Comment: I think it is always a good idea for any non-trivial program to have its constants (especially strings) in a separate file. Sometimes one must change them and then it is much easier to find them in that one single file than in all source files of an application. Not only for translations, but also when I check all my strings for a consistent use of words, commas, etc.    It is pretty simple to do this with the current refactoring capabilities in the Delphi IDE.

Comment: @James: if you choose readable names for the constants (I mean something more meaningful than sMsgText1), it makes a lot of sense to separate the strings, IMO. You know the advantages. I don't see any disadvantages, except that it takes some time. But the IDE can help you refactor such strings. Semy other reply too: it makes changing, spell and grammar checking, checking for consistency, etc. a LOT easier.

Comment: @Rudy "if you choose readable names for the constants" This is easy to say, not always so easy to do.

Comment: I think it is very easy. You can copy the text almost literally, just like the IDE does when it refactors such strings, or you give the intent for what it is used. I always do this, for a program or expert with more than a few units. I don't think my source files are made unreadable by it. On the contrary: my constant names reflect the intent, the purpose of the string, not the literal text. I think it makes the source code very readable, especially if the text is pretty long. Long texts can distract from the actual code.

Comment: I'm with Rudy all the way - aside from everything Rudy has explained. I find a Delphi source file littered with lots of long hard coded strings to be ugly and hard to read. strings I'm wondering if David doesn't have to 'go to declaration' option available in his version of Delphi...

Comment: @Mikey @Rudy Remember that OP has an existing codebase and no plans for translation. Are the benefits of changing worthwhile? Would the time spent making the change be the most profitable?

Comment: Even if there are no plans for translation, it is still necessary to change constants and string literals sometimes, e.g. to correct spelling, or to make them all use the same terms consistently, etc. Having them in one place is IMO the best way to achieve this. So there may be no direct benefit, but there is very likely a long term benefit, if this is a non-trivial program. Especially code you haven't looked at for more than 6 months is hard to grok again, and having your stuff in defined places makes such things a lot easier, IMO.

Comment: @david - "Are the benefits of changing worthwhile?" - absolutely, for the reasons explained. It's usually simple to accomplish and well worth it. Code full of hard coded string messages screams 'amateur'.

Comment: @mikey I guess I'm just an amateur then

Comment: @David - your reputation goes before you - obviously you are no amateur. Just that maybe some of your code has 'amateurish aspects'... LOL. So, time to refactor...(then again when isn't it 'time to refactor'... but we also have to get some work done....)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to translate your app, consider using Gnu GetText for delphi also known as [dxGetText](http://dxgettext.po.dk/).  This is better than putting your strings into a separate .pas file because it allows you to enable translation without any special tools, any recompilation, by even end users.

Comment: That is a good alternative indeed. I have translated a few such files to Dutch or German already for someone's programs. I never saw the source code, just the original text file in English and I sent back the translated file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the consensus here seems to tend towards the pro side, and I agree with that completely. Wrong overuse of string literals could lead to your source getting [stringly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303).

One benefit I am still missing is reusability of strings. Although that is not a direct benefit from the shipping to another unit, it ís from moving the string literals to constants.

But a rather significant drawback is the required time to create this separate source file. You might consider to implement this *good programming practice* in the next project. It entirely depends on whether you have sufficient time (e.g. hobby project) or a deadline, on having a next project or not (e.g. student), or on just wanting to do some practice. Like [David H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712117/strings-in-a-separate-pas-file/6712172#6712172) answers and comments, as with all decisions you make, you have to weight the benefits.

Seen apart from all kinds of fancy refactoring tools that could provide in some automatic assistance, realize that moving the string literals to another unit alone does not get the job done. Like [Rudy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712117/strings-in-a-separate-pas-file/6713794#6713794) and [David M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712117/strings-in-a-separate-pas-file/6728080#6728080) already answered, you partly have to rewrite your source. Also, finding readable, short and applicable constant names dóes take time. As many comments already stated that having control over spelling an consistency is important, I like to think that same argument goes for the replacing constants itself as well.

And about the translation answers, whether being applicable to OP or not, moving all your source strings to a separate unit is only part of a translation solution. You also have to take care for designer strings (i.e. captions), and GUI compatibility: a longer translation still has to fit in your label.

If you have the luxury or the need to: go for it. But I would take this to the next project.

Comment: I don't see what grouping string literals has to do with stringly typed.

Comment: @Marco Well, one example there says _"Message passing without using typed messages"_. But as _stringly typed_ is an imaginary term, I may have not understood its definition properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did group all literals with resourcestrings in an older version of our framework. I came back from that since in frameworks you might not use all strings in a framework (e.g. because some units or unit groups are not used, but scanning the common dirs will show up all strings in your translation tool).

Now I distribute them again over units. I originally started grouping them to avoid duplicates, but in retrospect that was the lesser problem

(*) using dxgettext on the "common" dirs.